# Hive: filtering data between specified dates in string format. Which one is optimised and why?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Which one should be preferred and why? My_date_column is of type string and of format YYYY-MM-DD

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_table
  WHERE my_date_column >= '2019-08-31' AND your_date_column <= '2019-09-02';
```

OR

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_table
  WHERE my_date_column in ('2019-08-31','2019-09-01','2019-09-02') ;
```

Lastly, In general, should I be storing my date as Date data type or simply as a string? I chose string type simply to handle any corrupt/badly formatted data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always store dates as `date` type. If you store them as strings it adds overhead to do any kind of arithmetic with the values (including those inequalities).

If you decided to ignore this advice and store dates as `string` anyway, then I believe the second form (the `IN` list) will be faster as it is comparing text string against text string. The other option, using inequalities, may not give the results you expect unless you explicitly `CAST(my_date_column as date)` and `CAST(your_date_column as date)`. Those cast will be applied to every record, which adds to the total cost of the query, and would be avoidable if those columns were stored as `date` instead.

A third option that you didn't mention is to use the `BETWEEN` operator (ie. `WHERE my_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date`). This is the same as using the two inequalities, but probably a bit cleaner and more idiomatic.

When in doubt, take a look at the `EXPLAIN` plans to understand how the query will be executed.